# How to apply a mapping function to CouchDB replication?

Tags: couchdb

I have a database on a powerful but distant CouchDB server (imagine a typical "cloud server").

I want to replicate this database to a local but less powerful computer (imagine a typical "mobile device" connected over a "slow network").

In the process, I'd like a mapping function (`view`?) to be applied to each source document on the powerful server prior to being transmitted over the network to the local machine. The intent is to reduce the size of the document by removing data elements which will not be required by processes that will be run on the local machine.

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/database/changes.html) for `/db/_changes` and noticed you can specify a `view`, but I'm completely unsure how to configure this as part of the replication source.

My use-case is different from the more common *filtered replication* that keeps coming up on Google searches, because that's focused on not replicating certain documents, while I want to replicate all documents in a given database, but not all data elements in each document.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You need to create a view on the CouchDB server and then [specify to use the view](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/database/changes.html#changes-filter-view) for the replication.

Inside that view, use a map function. For example, if you only want to retrieve the `_id` and the properties `key1` and `key2`, you can create a design doc via the Fauxton UI with a [map function](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/ddocs/ddocs.html#map-functions) like this:

```
map: function (doc) {
    emit(doc._id, { key1: doc.key1, key2: doc.key2 });
}
```